# Android Edittext into Listview action done

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I populate a listview with some EditText. Everything works perfectly, but when I press the Done button on the keyboard all the data are deleted in the EditText.
this is my code:

```
 final List<String> dettagli1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] array = {getString(R.string.user), getString(R.string.pass), getString(R.string.note)};
    for (String arr : array) {
        dettagli1.add(arr);
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.inflate_campo_text_no_delete, R.id.button12, array) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            MaterialEditText ed = (MaterialEditText) row.findViewById(R.id.button12);
            String d1 = dettagli1.get(position);
            ed.setFloatingLabelAlwaysShown(true);
            ed.setFloatingLabelText(d1);
            ed.setText("");
            return row;
        }
    };
     lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the xml file inflater

```
 <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:met_textColor="#848484"
    app:met_clearButton="true"
    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
    app:met_primaryColor="?colorAccent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use native components, but try to change this line in your xml: app:met_clearButton="true" remove it and test again.

Comment: why do you not intercept this event and override it? did you tried in other devices or only tested in one?